# Can't add Payment Pass on IOS Sumulator

Tags: ios, applepay, wallet, passkit

I'm trying to add a Payment Pass to Apple Wallet using PKAddPaymentPassViewController. However when i tried to call `PKAddPaymentPassViewController.canAddPaymentPass()` the result is always false.

When i call `PKAddPaymentPassViewController(requestConfiguration)` the app just crash with this error log:
`["The operation couldn’t be completed. (PKPassKitErrorDomain error 2.)"]`

We got our in-app provisioning entitlements approved by Apple, and i did add it to the app's entitlements.

Is this because Adding Payment Pass is not possible on simulators? Or am i missing something?

Comment: I don't believe that you can add a payment pass to a simulator. `canAddPaymentPass` is telling you that.